# How to apply same VisualState to many controls?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am try to learn about VisualState in WPF. I am able to make a simple VisualState in WPF. But the Problem is how can i apply same VisualState to other controls.

Here is my sample VisualState Code.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{x:Null}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1">
                    <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager.TransitionEffect>
                        <ee:FadeTransitionEffect/>
                    </ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager.TransitionEffect>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="MySate">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFF31515"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
        <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
    </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>

    <Grid Height="132" Margin="58,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="230">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Margin="54,37,35,48" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" Background="Black"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Height="132" Margin="58,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="230">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Margin="54,37,35,48" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" Background="Black"/>
    </Grid>
    <Button x:Name="yyyyy" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="70" Margin="0,8,30,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148" Click="Clickbd"/>
</Grid>
```

C# :

```
private void Clickbd(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(LayoutRoot, "MySate", true);
}
```

This VisualState successfully work for **TextBlock** control. I want to apply this VisualState on  **textBlock2**

Thank`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add your `VisualState` to a template that can be shared between different controls.

I haven't tested the code, but something like this should do the trick:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBlock">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
              <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                  <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1">
                      <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager.TransitionEffect>
                          <ee:FadeTransitionEffect/>
                      </ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager.TransitionEffect>
                  </VisualTransition>
              </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
              <VisualState x:Name="MySate">
                  <Storyboard>
                      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                          <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFF31515"/>
                      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
          </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
          <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
        </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>

        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" />
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Can you you give me an example ?

Comment: I just noticed that while my fingers wrote `TextBlock`, my mind was thinking `TextBox`, so the code above probably needs to be modified to make it work as expected.